# Vinagre (Remote Desktop): How to enter Alt+F2?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, vinagre

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 on my local machine to connect to a remote desktop which also Ubuntu 20.04.1 (server). The remote server was converted to a "desktop" using `apt install ubuntu-desktop` and then XRDP was installed using `apt install xrdp`. For the configuration of XRDP, roughly the information given at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/xrdp was used. I am using ***Vinagre*** on the local machine to connect to the remote desktop.

A installed also the *Dash to Panel* extension on the desktop user of the remote server. However, this extension has a bug: When a click on the "*Show Applications*" button (the button with nine white dots) and try to do a "*Search*", the `gnome-shell` process for that user starts to use 100% CPU and the desktop becomes unresponsive. The solution is to kill this process. However, an easier method would be to press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `r` in the command input box.

However, I am not able to enter <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> on the remote desktop even when *Viagre* is in full screen: The key combination is processed by the local machine.

How can I send <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to the remote desktop in Viagre?

Comment: Have you ever tried when the remote desktop is normally working Alt+F2 from local machine and does it work?

Comment: @UnKNOWn - As I mentioned in my OP, when I press Alt+F2 while the remote desktop is active, the key sequence is processed ***locally***. After that, if I enter the `r` command and press Enter, the ***local*** `gnome-shell` is restarted, not the `gnome-shell` in the remote desktop.

Comment: Ok thats clear.. My point is.. If the shell is not responsive Alt+F2 will not work..

Comment: I Would open terminal in the remote desktop and give this command. But when the shell is not responsive you cant do anything.. `gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval 'Main.runDialog.open()'`