# Getting stuck on a glitch that looks like a combo of show applications and the activities screen

Tags: gnome, 20.04, appmenu, activities-overview

If I click the super key (the one with windows symbol on it), or super A or I click on the 9 dotted square for show applications, I get stuck in a screen that is a combination of show applications and the activities screen. It is REALLY ANNOYING and I miss my original functioning Ubuntu.

My only way to get out so far has been to restart gnome with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, then typing r and clicking enter.
I want to add a snippet of my syslog but askubuntu is labelling it spam. Please can someone help me.

Comment: Your problem seems very similar to mine: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268974/vinagre-remote-desktop-how-to-enter-altf2 Are you using a physical system or a remote one?

Comment: It's a physical one, but I see it was because of the dashtopanel extension which I disabled.

Comment: Hi! I'm facing the same glitch since 20.10 and I'm using dashtodock however disabling that does not solve the issue... Any other ideas? I can't seem to find a keyboard shortcut to edit/remove this conflicting key.

Comment: Same here with Dash to Dock, Ubuntu 21.04.